# WordPress Admin Blank but Menu Visible

Tags: wordpress

A client site of mine has recently had an issue that all admin pages are blank. But for some reason the menu is visible and clickable.

When I download the site to localhost it works fine. I've tried removing the plugins folder and renaming the theme in use with no luck.

What could suddenly cause this issue?

My client says that he has no tried to update WP core or any plugins.

URL: letitgrowhydro . co. uk

Thanks

Comment: did you check the error logs on the server?

Comment: I can't see anything in the error log worth mentioning.

Comment: do you use any caching?

Comment: if the front-end of the site works, and we cannot login to the backend, how are we supposed to actually debug your problem?

Comment: I was hoping that someone may have experience with this issue before or perhaps someone may have a few ideas. I understand these issues can be hard to track down. But any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not programming related

Comment: See [Debugging in WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress), but the first step is to disable all plugins.

Comment: I had the same problem and the accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21614237/what-would-cause-wordpress-admin-screen-to-be-blank-except-for-nav-bar fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A client of mine had a similar issue caused by an error on wp-admin/includes/screen.php. I Did a manual update to 3.8 and it fixed the issue.

If you are not on 3.8 yet please upgrade first.