# What would cause WordPress admin screen to be blank, except for nav bar?

Tags: php, wordpress

So I've read through all the similar questions and can't find a solution here.  Basically the user-facing site looks fine and is functioning properly.  The WP Admin, however, shows only the left navigation menu... and nothing more.

I've tried all the basic solutions -- removing themes, removing plugins, turning on error reporting, and all that I get is a few typical warnings.

The admin was working fine a week or two ago - and I haven't been in it since.  Also, it's a couple of versions old - but he original designer of this site warned NOT to upgrade WordPress or it would break the code.

So I thought I'd post the page source here to see if anyone may have a suggestion as to where to look from here.  NOTE, this is the WPADMIN page source, not the the source from the website.

Here's a screenshot of what I'm seeing.[image: Screen Shot Here]

Here is what I get when I login to the WP ADMIN:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 8]>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="ie8"  dir="ltr" lang="en-US">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !(IE 8) ]><!-->
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  dir="ltr" lang="en-US">
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Dashboard &lsaquo; Suncoast Surgical Associates | Tampa and Brandon, Florida General Surgery and Laparoscopic Surgery &#8212; WordPress</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
addLoadEvent = function(func){if(typeof jQuery!="undefined")jQuery(document).ready(func);else if(typeof wpOnload!='function'){wpOnload=func;}else{var oldonload=wpOnload;wpOnload=function(){oldonload();func();}}};
var userSettings = {
        'url': '/',
        'uid': '3',
        'time':'1391720939'
    },
    ajaxurl = 'http://suncoastsurgicalassociates.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
    pagenow = 'dashboard',
    typenow = '',
    adminpage = 'index-php',
    thousandsSeparator = ',',
    decimalPoint = '.',
    isRtl = 0;
</script>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='http://suncoastsurgicalassociates.com/wp-admin/load-styles.php?c=1&amp;dir=ltr&amp;load=admin-bar,wp-admin&amp;ver=7f0753feec257518ac1fec83d5bced6a' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='thickbox-css'  href='http://suncoastsurgicalassociates.com/wp-includes/js/thickbox/thickbox.css?ver=20111117' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='colors-css'  href='http://suncoastsurgicalassociates.com/wp-admin/css/colors-fresh.css?ver=20111206' type='text/css' media='all' />
<!--[if lte IE 7]>
<link rel='stylesheet' id='ie-css'  href='http://suncoastsurgicalassociates.com/wp-admin/css/ie.css?ver=20111130' type='text/css' media='all' />
<![endif]-->
<link rel='stylesheet' id='akismet.css-css'  href='http://suncoastsurgicalassociates.com/wp-content/plugins/akismet/akismet.css?ver=2.5.4.4' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='jcrop_style-css'  href='http://suncoastsurgicalassociates.com/wp-content/plugins/scissors-continued/css/jquery.Jcrop.css?ver=3.3.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='scissors_style-css'  href='http://suncoastsurgicalassociates.com/wp-content/plugins/scissors-continued/css/scissors.css?ver=3.3.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var WPAkismet = {"comment_author_url_nonce":"3190b6c9aa"};
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://suncoastsurgicalassociates.com/wp-admin/load-scripts.php?c=1&amp;load=jquery,utils&amp;ver=edec3fab0cb6297ea474806db1895fa7'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://suncoastsurgicalassociates.com/wp-content/plugins/akismet/akismet.js?ver=2.5.4.6'></script>
    <style type="text/css">
    #adminmenu .toplevel_page_formidable div.wp-menu-image{background: url(http://suncoastsurgicalassociates.com/wp-content/plugins/formidable/images/form_16.png) no-repeat center;}
    </style>    
    <style type="text/css" media="print">#wpadminbar { display:none; }</style>
</head>
<body class="wp-admin no-js  index-php admin-bar branch-3-3 version-3-3-1 admin-color-fresh">
<script type="text/javascript">document.body.className = document.body.className.replace('no-js','js');</script>

<div id="wpwrap">

<div id="adminmenuback"></div>
<div id="adminmenuwrap">
<div id="adminmenushadow"></div>
<ul id="adminmenu" role="navigation">


    <li class="wp-first-item wp-has-submenu wp-has-current-submenu wp-menu-open menu-top menu-top-first menu-icon-dashboard menu-top-last" id="menu-dashboard">
    <div class='wp-menu-image'><a href='index.php'><br /></a></div><div class="wp-menu-arrow"><div></div></div><a href='index.php' class="wp-first-item wp-has-submenu wp-has-current-submenu wp-menu-open menu-top menu-top-first menu-icon-dashboard menu-top-last" tabindex="1">Dashboard</a>
    <div class='wp-submenu'><div class='wp-submenu-wrap'><div class='wp-submenu-head'>Dashboard</div><ul><li class="wp-first-item current"><a href='index.php' class="wp-first-item current" tabindex="1">Home</a></li><li><a href='update-core.php' tabindex="1">Updates <span class='update-plugins count-3' title='1 WordPress Update, 2 Theme Updates'><span class='update-count'>3</span></span></a></li><li><a href='index.php?page=akismet-stats-display' tabindex="1">Akismet Stats</a></li></ul></div></div></li>
    <li class="wp-not-current-submenu wp-menu-separator"><div class="separator"></div></li>
    <li class="wp-has-submenu wp-not-current-submenu open-if-no-js menu-top menu-icon-post menu-top-first" id="menu-posts">
    <div class='wp-menu-image'><a href='edit.php'><br /></a></div><div class="wp-menu-arrow"><div></div></div><a href='edit.php' class="wp-has-submenu wp-not-current-submenu open-if-no-js menu-top menu-icon-post menu-top-first" tabindex="1" aria-haspopup="true">Posts</a>
    <div class='wp-submenu'><div class='wp-submenu-wrap'><div class='wp-submenu-head'>Posts</div><ul><li class="wp-first-item"><a href='edit.php' class="wp-first-item" tabindex="1">All Posts</a></li><li><a href='post-new.php' tabindex="1">Add New</a></li><li><a href='edit-tags.php?taxonomy=category' tabindex="1">Categories</a></li><li><a href='edit-tags.php?taxonomy=post_tag' tabindex="1">Tags</a></li></ul></div></div></li>
    <li class="wp-has-submenu wp-not-current-submenu menu-top menu-icon-media" id="menu-media">
    <div class='wp-menu-image'><a href='upload.php'><br /></a></div><div class="wp-menu-arrow"><div></div></div><a href='upload.php' class="wp-has-submenu wp-not-current-submenu menu-top menu-icon-media" tabindex="1" aria-haspopup="true">Media</a>
    <div class='wp-submenu'><div class='wp-submenu-wrap'><div class='wp-submenu-head'>Media</div><ul><li class="wp-first-item"><a href='upload.php' class="wp-first-item" tabindex="1">Library</a></li><li><a href='media-new.php' tabindex="1">Add New</a></li></ul></div></div></li>
    <li class="wp-has-submenu wp-not-current-submenu menu-top menu-icon-links" id="menu-links">
    <div class='wp-menu-image'><a href='link-manager.php'><br /></a></div><div class="wp-menu-arrow"><div></div></div><a href='link-manager.php' class="wp-has-submenu wp-not-current-submenu menu-top menu-icon-links" tabindex="1" aria-haspopup="true">Links</a>
    <div class='wp-submenu'><div class='wp-submenu-wrap'><div class='wp-submenu-head'>Links</div><ul><li class="wp-first-item"><a href='link-manager.php' class="wp-first-item" tabindex="1">All Links</a></li><li><a href='link-add.php' tabindex="1">Add New</a></li><li><a href='edit-tags.php?taxonomy=link_category' tabindex="1">Link Categories</a></li></ul></div></div></li>
    <li class="wp-has-submenu wp-not-current-submenu menu-top menu-icon-page" id="menu-pages">
    <div class='wp-menu-image'><a href='edit.php?post_type=page'><br /></a></div><div class="wp-menu-arrow"><div></div></div><a href='edit.php?post_type=page' class="wp-has-submenu wp-not-current-submenu menu-top menu-icon-page" tabindex="1" aria-haspopup="true">Pages</a>
    <div class='wp-submenu'><div class='wp-submenu-wrap'><div class='wp-submenu-head'>Pages</div><ul><li class="wp-first-item"><a href='edit.php?post_type=page' class="wp-first-item" tabindex="1">All Pages</a></li><li><a href='post-new.php?post_type=page' tabindex="1">Add New</a></li></ul></div></div></li>
    <li class="wp-not-current-submenu menu-top menu-icon-comments menu-top-last" id="menu-comments">
    <div class='wp-menu-image'><a href='edit-comments.php'><br /></a></div><div class="wp-menu-arrow"><div></div></div><a href='edit-comments.php' class="wp-not-current-submenu menu-top menu-icon-comments menu-top-last" tabindex="1">Comments <span class='awaiting-mod count-1'><span class='pending-count'>1</span></span></a></li>
    <li class="wp-not-current-submenu wp-menu-separator"><div class="separator"></div></li>
    <li class="wp-has-submenu wp-not-current-submenu menu-top menu-icon-appearance menu-top-first" id="menu-appearance">
    <div class='wp-menu-image'><a href='themes.php'><br /></a></div><div class="wp-menu-arrow"><div></div></div><a href='themes.php' class="wp-has-submenu wp-not-current-submenu menu-top menu-icon-appearance menu-top-first" tabindex="1" aria-haspopup="true">Appearance</a>
    <div class='wp-submenu'><div class='wp-submenu-wrap'><div class='wp-submenu-head'>Appearance</div><ul><li class="wp-first-item"><a href='themes.php' class="wp-first-item" tabindex="1">Themes</a></li><li><a href='widgets.php' tabindex="1">Widgets</a></li><li><a href='theme-editor.php' tabindex="1">Editor</a></li></ul></div></div></li>
    <li class="wp-has-submenu wp-not-current-submenu menu-top menu-icon-plugins" id="menu-plugins">
    <div class='wp-menu-image'><a href='plugin-install.php'><br /></a></div><div class="wp-menu-arrow"><div></div></div><a href='plugin-install.php' class="wp-has-submenu wp-not-current-submenu menu-top menu-icon-plugins" tabindex="1" aria-haspopup="true">Plugins </a>
    <div class='wp-submenu'><div class='wp-submenu-wrap'><div class='wp-submenu-head'>Plugins </div><ul><li class="wp-first-item"><a href='plugin-install.php' class="wp-first-item" tabindex="1">Add New</a></li><li><a href='plugin-install.php?page=akismet-key-config' tabindex="1">Akismet Configuration</a></li></ul></div></div></li>
    <li class="wp-has-submenu wp-not-current-submenu menu-top menu-icon-users" id="menu-users">
    <div class='wp-menu-image'><a href='profile.php'><br /></a></div><div class="wp-menu-arrow"><div></div></div><a href='profile.php' class="wp-has-submenu wp-not-current-submenu menu-top menu-icon-users" tabindex="1" aria-haspopup="true">Profile</a>
    <div class='wp-submenu'><div class='wp-submenu-wrap'><div class='wp-submenu-head'>Profile</div><ul><li class="wp-first-item"><a href='profile.php' class="wp-first-item" tabindex="1">Your Profile</a></li><li><a href='user-new.php' tabindex="1">Add New User</a></li></ul></div></div></li>
    <li class="wp-has-submenu wp-not-current-submenu menu-top menu-icon-tools" id="menu-tools">
    <div class='wp-menu-image'><a href='tools.php'><br /></a></div><div class="wp-menu-arrow"><div></div></div><a href='tools.php' class="wp-has-submenu wp-not-current-submenu menu-top menu-icon-tools" tabindex="1" aria-haspopup="true">Tools</a>
    <div class='wp-submenu'><div class='wp-submenu-wrap'><div class='wp-submenu-head'>Tools</div><ul><li class="wp-first-item"><a href='tools.php' class="wp-first-item" tabindex="1">Available Tools</a></li><li><a href='import.php' tabindex="1">Import</a></li><li><a href='export.php' tabindex="1">Export</a></li></ul></div></div></li>
    <li class="wp-has-submenu wp-not-current-submenu menu-top menu-icon-settings menu-top-last" id="menu-settings">
    <div class='wp-menu-image'><a href='options-general.php'><br /></a></div><div class="wp-menu-arrow"><div></div></div><a href='options-general.php' class="wp-has-submenu wp-not-current-submenu menu-top menu-icon-settings menu-top-last" tabindex="1" aria-haspopup="true">Settings</a>
    <div class='wp-submenu'><div class='wp-submenu-wrap'><div class='wp-submenu-head'>Settings</div><ul><li class="wp-first-item"><a href='options-general.php' class="wp-first-item" tabindex="1">General</a></li><li><a href='options-writing.php' tabindex="1">Writing</a></li><li><a href='options-reading.php' tabindex="1">Reading</a></li><li><a href='options-discussion.php' tabindex="1">Discussion</a></li><li><a href='options-media.php' tabindex="1">Media</a></li><li><a href='options-privacy.php' tabindex="1">Privacy</a></li><li><a href='options-permalink.php' tabindex="1">Permalinks</a></li><li><a href='options-general.php?page=fancybox-for-wordpress' tabindex="1">Fancybox for WP</a></li><li><a href='options-general.php?page=mappress' tabindex="1">MapPress</a></li></ul></div></div></li><li id="collapse-menu" class="hide-if-no-js"><div id="collapse-button"><div></div></div><span>Collapse menu</span></li></ul>
</div>
<div id="wpcontent">


<div id="wpbody">

<div id="wpbody-content">
        <div id="screen-meta" class="metabox-prefs">

            <div id="contextual-help-wrap" class="hidden">
                <div id="contextual-help-back"></div>
                <div id="contextual-help-columns">
                    <div class="contextual-help-tabs">
                        <ul>

                            <li id="tab-link-overview" class="active">
                                <a href="#tab-panel-overview">
                                    Overview                                </a>
                            </li>

                            <li id="tab-link-help-navigation" class="">
                                <a href="#tab-panel-help-navigation">
                                    Navigation                              </a>
                            </li>

                            <li id="tab-link-help-layout" class="">
                                <a href="#tab-panel-help-layout">
                                    Layout                              </a>
                            </li>

                            <li id="tab-link-help-content" class="">
                                <a href="#tab-panel-help-content">
                                    Content                             </a>
                            </li>
                                                </ul>
                    </div>

                                        <div class="contextual-help-sidebar">
```

I noticed that the help sidebar is where it ends.  Yet that doesn't give me anywhere specific to look.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks...

Comment: My Wordpress fu is a little rusty but open up `wp-config.php` and set the [`WP_DEBUG`](http://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG) constant to `true`. Also, what *warnings* are you getting. They're probably important

Comment: "The original designer of this site warned **NOT** to upgrade WordPress or it would break the code"... This is a nice one :)

Comment: Yes. I'm not sure "person who hands one a ticking parcel and then runs away with their fingers stuck in their ears" is actually the right job description for "designer".

Comment: What warnings you are getting? What is your WordPress version? Which plugins are you using? Have you updated any plugin lately? Does any other link from your left menu works?

Comment: It looks like you're running into a PHP error and have error reporting turned off. That would explain why you're code simply stops.

Comment: We have tried turning on error reporting (as I mentioned) and there was only one message - and it was corrected (simple mis-behaved plug-in).  After that, no more error messages - same result - white screen but menu on the left.

Comment: @Phil  We did turn on debug - it's on. Nothing new.  And all warnings are gone now after correcting the plug-in bug.  Wasn't significant anyway - was just missing an "isset" and we added it.  So no more warning and still the same result.

Comment: Just an FYI.. we have added no plugins, and tried (of course) to disable all plugins.  We renamed the plugins folder, and added a new blank one.  Nothing.  Same issue.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Ok.. found it.

This was the offending code, and it was in `wp-admin\includes\screen.php` on line 706:

```
<?php echo self::$this->_help_sidebar; ?>
```

It should be:

```
<?php echo $this->_help_sidebar; ?>
```

Have no idea why this suddenly decided to go bad.  And frankly I'm not sure I'll ever find out.

But wanted to help others if possible.

Take care everyone.. and thanks...

Comment: It should be `echo $this->_help_sidebar`, without `self`.

Comment: Any idea on what causes this? Would be mega handy to understand why this happened.

Comment: Thanks for the solution - and Id also love to know what causes this issue - is it a change in php version?

Answer (score 6):

FYI, I had the exact same problem, and this solution worked for me.  ie:
change:

```
echo self::$this->_help_sidebar;
```

to

```
echo $this->_help_sidebar;
```

Comment: This adds nothing to the answer that was posted 3 months before this one...

Answer (score 0):

Indeed this worked for me too, changing to

```
<?php echo $this->_help_sidebar; ?>
```

I believe it is a matter of the php version we use

Check here to understantd self:: functionality :

http://www.diffen.com/difference/self_(PHP)_vs_this_(PHP)