# Wordpress admin panel is coming blank

Tags: wordpress

[image]

When i moved my wordpress from one hosting to another , the admin panel is coming blank . No option is working , it just refreshes and right side of panel remains blank . 
Please help i am not able to do any change in website .
Website is working fine .

Answer (score 0):

First of all, deactivate all plugins by renaming the "plugins" folder by "plugins.hold" (into wp-content).

Then try to login to your WordPress Admin and see if it works.

If that does not resolve your issue, access your server via FTP, navigate to /wp-content/themes/ and rename the directory of your currently active theme. This will force the Default theme. Again, try to login to your admin.

If it doesn't work, check if you have an .htaccess file on your root folder. If so, rename it by "htaccess.txt".

Let me know if one of these solutions fix your problem.
Cheers,
Dam

Comment: No , i tried all steps , it is not working .
When i rename theme folder , site is not working .

Comment: got the solution
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21614237/what-would-cause-wordpress-admin-screen-to-be-blank-except-for-nav-bar